# ¿Cómo mantengo el color de la fuente de mi dropdown menu luego de clic?

Tags: bootstrap

Mi problema es que en el nav quiero mantener el color de la fuente del menú desplegable luego de darle clic. Porque aunque este es mi código:

```
nav.navbar ul.nav ul.dropdown a {
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-size: 12pt; 
  text-shadow: black 0.1em 0.1em 0.2em; 
  color: white; 
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav.navbar ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li{
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-size: 12pt; 
  text-shadow: black 0.1em 0.1em 0.2em; 
  color: white; 
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav.navbar ul.nav li a:hover{
  color: #00a033;
}

nav.navbar ul.nav li {
  background-color: #001b5c;
}

/* cambiar el color de fondo a la barra */
nav.navbar {
  background-color: #001b5c;
}

.nav > li.active > a:hover,
.nav > li.active > a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Pasa lo siguiente:
[![Lo veo así][1]][1]
[![Luego se ve así][2]][2]
[image: Y me queda así:(]

Y quiero que se quede en blanco la palabra servicios, haya hecho clic y no en ese gris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

creo que la solución a tu problema sería esto:

```
.nav > li.active > a:visited  {
  color: white; /*O tu color*/
}
```

O en su defecto:

```
.nav > li.active > a:focus {
  color: white; /*O tu color*/
}
```

Que luego que se le haya dado click al botón estará en blanco.

Comment: Voy a probar con el visited también y te comento! Gracias. Lo coloqué así y funcionó también: nav.navbar ul.nav li a:focus{
     text-decoration: none;
     background-color:  #001b5c;
  color: white;
}

Comment: Ummmm.... Wilfredo el focus me lo resolvió. Sin embargo, gracias porque no sabía que podía manejar el atributo visited. Saludos.

Comment: @Akyna de Nada, no había leído el final de tu código bien, pero esa es otra vía.